# Correspondence between SCSI device entries in /sys and the disks in /dev

Tags: linux, devices, disk, scsi

Under the `/sys/class/scsi_device` folder I have the following:

```
 root@linux01:/sys/class/scsi_device # ls
 1:0:0:0  2:0:0:0  2:0:1:0  3:0:0:0
```

How can I know how each of these devices is related to the disk?

For example, how can I determine if device `2:0:1:0` is disk `/dev/sdb`?

```
root@linux01:/sys/class/scsi_device # sfdisk -s
/dev/sdb:  15728640
/dev/sdc: 524288000
/dev/sda:    153600
[...]
# more /etc/redhat-release  ( Linux VM machine ) 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to get the correspondence is to look at the `device/block` subdirectory in the `/sys` hierarchy:

```
# ls -1d /sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/block/*
/sys/class/scsi_device/1:0:0:0/device/block/sr0
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:1:0/device/block/sdb
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:2:0/device/block/sdc
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:3:0/device/block/sdd
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:4:0/device/block/sde
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:5:0/device/block/sdf
```

The directory name in there correspond to the block device name in `/dev`.