# How to find the SCSI ID of a disk in QTS?

Tags: linux, sysfs, scsi

Normally, in Linux, one can use `lsscsi` to map disk devices to their SCSI ID:

```
# lsscsi -d
[N:0:4:1]    disk    SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L7__1              /dev/nvme0n1 [259:0]
[N:1:5:1]    disk    SAMSUNG MZALQ512HBLU-00BL1__1              /dev/nvme1n1 [259:4]
```

QTS, however, is a strangely under-equipped version of Linux (Redhat?). I need to be able to map SCSI devices to the system's device names, somehow: however, even when I have installed `lsscsi` in the system, the output is not useful:

```
[admin@CoMind-UniCron ~]# ./lsscsi -d       
[0:0:0:0]    disk    Samsung  SSD 870 QVO 8TB  SVQ0  -        
[1:0:0:0]    disk    Samsung  SSD 870 QVO 8TB  SVQ0  -        
[2:0:0:0]    disk    Samsung  SSD 870 QVO 8TB  SVQ0  -        
[3:0:0:0]    disk    Samsung  SSD 870 QVO 8TB  SVQ0  -        
[4:0:0:0]    disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[5:0:0:0]    disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[6:0:0:0]    disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[7:0:0:0]    disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[9:0:0:0]    disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[10:0:0:0]   disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[11:0:0:0]   disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[32:0:0:0]   disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[33:0:0:0]   disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[34:0:0:0]   disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[35:0:0:0]   disk    Seagate  ST20000NE000-3G5 EN01  -        
[56:0:0:0]   disk    ADATA    IUM3M-005GMHS    1100  -
```

I'm sure there must be a way to find the information by digging around in `/proc` and `/sys` - but how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correspondence between SCSI device entries in /sys and the disks in /dev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268429/correspondence-between-scsi-device-entries-in-sys-and-the-disks-in-dev) e.g. `ls -1d /sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/block/* | cut -d '/' -f5,8`

Comment: No, unfortunately not - the `block/` subdirectory is missing

Comment: Look also under `/sys/bus/scsi/devices/` if you see them there, normally you'd have paths like `/sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0/block/sda` ... The other way is via `lsblk --scsi` or `lsblk -do hctl,name` but only if your `lsblk` is v.3.23 or newer. BTW, what kernel does that system run on?

Comment: @don_crissti The kernel is `5.10.60-qnap`, and it seems to be something Redhat-ish, with certain changes to the kernel, although it mostly seems to be stuff meant to stop people from inspecting the system too closely. `block/` seems to have been removed from `/sys` altogether. I think, in the long run, the right thing to do is to either install a proper Linux, or perhaps sell the thing to some unsuspecting soul ;-)